# A better way to find adjoint of a $3 \times 3$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Today in class of matrices, I learnt how to find out adjoint of a matrix. The professor told that it was a matrix of same order formed by cofactors of corresponding elements of a matrix and then its transpose. But the way is too long. So I'm curious whether there's a shorter way to deal with it and an example followed by explanation would be a great help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $\;\DeclareMathOperator{\adj}{adj} \adj(A)\,A=\det(A) I$, you have $\;\adj(A)=\det(A)A^{-1}$.

Then you can use Gauß's pivot method to calculate both $\;\det(A)$ and $\;A^{-1}$, which is  faster than computing the cofactors.

Comment: Thats good. Thanks

Comment: Well, this does not work when det(A) = 0. In my opinion the advantage of the adjoint over the inverse is that it is also defined for singular matrices...

Comment: Yes, for  a singular matrix, you have to compute $n^2$ subdeterminants.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) list a rather simple expression for the adjoint (or adjugate) of a 3 x 3 matrix. It reads

$\text{adj}(A) = 1/2 ( \text{tr}(A)^2 - \text{tr}(A^2) ) I - A \text{tr}(A) + A^2$

with $\text{tr}(A)$ denoting the trace of a matrix, which is the sum of the diagonal elements. So the formula for adj(A) only needs calculation of the square matrix $A^2$ and some additional more or less trivial operations (trace and matrix addition). Whether this is "shorter" than the direct way probably depends on the matrix A and whether you already know $A^2$ or not.